# Header in a box, with dynamic content

Tags: tables, header-footer, memoir

I'd like to reproduce this header :
[image: Header model]

I would like it to appear at the top of every page, with the default font, and the date and the page should update dynamically. The "edition" and "reference" field should be configurable for the whole document.

Here is the code I tried:

```
\newcommand{\refdoc}{SERB-ArbreProduit-0-001}
\newcommand{\editiondoc}{1}
\newcommand{\dateedition}{\date}
\newcommand{\revisiondoc}{}
\newcommand{\daterevision}{}

\newcommand{\testheader}{%
  Réf.~:~\refdoc\\
  Édition~:~\editiondoc\qquad Date~:~\dateedition\\
  Révision~:~\revisiondoc\qquad Date~:~\daterevision\\
  \begin{flushright}
    \thepage
  \end{flushright}
}

\copypagestyle{test}{empty}
\makepagestyle{test}
\makeevenhead{test}{SERB}{}{\testheader}
\makeoddhead{test}{SERB}{}{\testheader}
```

(I use the `memoir` class.) However, this does not change the default header and footer (with the chapter title). Besides, I'm not sure how to put it in a box. Could I use a table? If so, would the spacing of the header be manageable?

Comment: +1 for saying you want the default font (and not the one in the picture, which I don't dare write the name of). `;-)`

Comment: \fbox, \framebox, tikz nodes (pictures) and \colorbox can be used in headers, but memoir is a world unto itself.

Comment: @egreg: Let's call it the Lord Voldemort of the Fonts ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Not perfect, but I've got the general outline:

```
\newcommand*{\refdoc}{SERB-DM-1.1-001}
\newcommand*{\editiondoc}{1}
\newcommand*{\dateedition}{\today}
\newcommand*{\revisiondoc}{\phantom{1}}
\newcommand*{\daterevision}{\phantom{\today}}

\newcommand*{\myheader}{%
  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.48\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{images/cnes.jpg}
    \hfill
    \Huge SERB
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{images/LATMOS.jpg}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \vline\
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.48\linewidth}
    \begin{flushright}
      Réf.~:\quad\refdoc\protect\\
      Édition~:~\editiondoc\qquad Date~:~\dateedition\protect\\
      Révision~:~\revisiondoc\qquad Date~:~\daterevision\protect\\
      \thepage\
    \end{flushright}
  \end{minipage}
}

\copypagestyle{serb}{empty}
\makepagestyle{serb}
\makeevenhead{serb}{\fbox{\myheader}}{}{}
\makeoddhead{serb}{\fbox{\myheader}}{}{}
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{serb}
\aliaspagestyle{title}{serb}
```

And it gives this:
[image: Header]

As you can see, the vertical line is not perfect (not the exact size of the `\fbox`), but I didn't find how to tweak this.

Comment: Do you know if your solution works with Memoir?